# OpenGL C - How would I go about drawing a line trail from a planet?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I have a 3D environment set up and a planet moving through space.

Every time the planet moves, I append it's X,Y,Z co-ordinates into a float array.

I would like to draw a line strip that connects from each of the historical points that displays where the planet has been.

I'm not sure how to go about this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an array which stores all the coordinates through time. The simplest way would be to create a large array at the start of your program, or you can create a dynamic sized array.

Where ever you update your scene, at the end you can put a for loop which draws a line between `i` and `i+1` elements of the coordinates array. Sth like this would do it:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
//your for loop
glEnd();
```